# Why is a role of Setter in DTO

Tags: java, oop, object, dto

Assume a creator of DTO "foo" and a recipient of DTO "bar". I can understand that along with a constructor, creator "foo" would need a setter. My question expanded - Is there any reason when "bar" would use a setter ?

Answer (score 1):

If bar is just a recipient, then probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. But you don't have to have setters in the dto if there are not many enough to make using them as parameters in the constructor method too ugly.

Comment: You may need setters if the value you need is not present at time object creation.

Comment: Usually is. Because he is talking about the data transfer objects so for solid design you may not want to change fields along the way.